# Unable to load data file in Julia

Tags: julia

There is a CSV file called orders_data stored in my system, but when I try to load this file in Julia using readdlm command in Jupyter Notebook(running in my browser), it says "NO SUCH FILE DIRECTORY FOUND"

I'm not sure why does this happen? is there a specific location where the files need to be stored to be accessed using Julia command? is it that I need to install some packages first to load the file using browser version of jupyter?

```
//Error information
```

SystemError: opening file orders_data.csv: No such file or directory

Comment: Type the function `pwd()` in Julia and compare it with the full pathname of your file. If they don't match, then you need to do a `cd(pathname)` first.

Comment: @daycaster, Thank you so much! I'm grateful to you. This solved my problem

Comment: Cool. I made an answer for you to accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working directory is set to your current location when you start a Julia session. You can see what it is by calling the `pwd()` function. You can change it by calling the `cd()` function. Unless you specify otherwise, or provide a more complete pathname, Julia looks for files in your current working directory (although it's different for modules).